# To concatenate more than two video using FFMPEG

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I've been working on FFMPEG, this is indeed not an easy task since I've succeeded in doing some work. I'm done with concatenating two videos using ffmpeg but somehow when it comes to more than two it does not work. So I'm finding out some command to do my task.

The thing I did is to merge two videos are :

```
String complexCommand[] = {"-y", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
             "[0:v]scale=1920x1080,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v] scale=iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih):ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih), pad=1920:1080:(1920-iw*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2:(1080-ih*min(1920/iw\\,1080/ih))/2,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
             "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "1920x1080", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-q","4","-preset", "ultrafast", savingPath};
```

The above is working fine for two videos. I've tried altering my code for three videos but it does not work.

What I've done in the above code is :

- Added one more input after the second one
- Changed the **concat=3:v=1:a=1**

But it does not merge and gave me this error in my LogCat :

```
FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                       built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                       configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                       libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                       libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                       libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                       libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                       libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                       libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                       libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                       libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                     Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4':
                                                       Metadata:
                                                         major_brand     : isom
                                                         minor_version   : 512
                                                         compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
                                                         encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                       Duration: 00:02:47.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 245 kb/s
                                                         Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 112 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                         Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                     Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4':
                                                       Metadata:
                                                         major_brand     : mp42
                                                         minor_version   : 0
                                                         compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                         creation_time   : 2013-12-15 13:11:41
                                                       Duration: 00:03:51.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1693 kb/s
                                                         Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1498 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                         Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           creation_time   : 2013-12-15 13:11:41
                                                           handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
                                                     Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/DCIM/Sinha's POP/20150530_073113.mp4':
                                                       Metadata:
                                                         major_brand     : isom
                                                         minor_version   : 0
                                                         compatible_brands: isom3gp4
                                                         creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                       Duration: 00:04:48.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3608 kb/s
                                                         Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, 3478 kb/s, 30.28 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                           handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                           encoder         :                                
                                                         Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                           handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                     [Parsed_setsar_1 @ 0xa9ea9220] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
                                                     [Parsed_setsar_4 @ 0xa9ea9310] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
                                                     [Parsed_setsar_1 @ 0xa9ea92c0] num:den syntax is deprecated, please use num/den or named options instead
                                                     [Parsed_setsar_4 @ 0xa9ea93b0] num:den syntax is deprecated, please us
```

I've tried one more command which works fine for concatenating two videos but still it does not work for more than two videos :

```
String complexCommand[] = {"-y", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/DCIM/Sinha's POP/20150530_073113.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1",
            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "480x640", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-q","4","-preset", "ultrafast", savingPath};
```

You can clearly see in the above code that I've tried using this for the three videos but still no luck. Will appreciate your help. Thanks.

**EDITS**

After following the LordNeckbeard's suggestion from the comment section, I've used his suggestion in my code but after doing that still no luck however the console's output got changed and here is the command which I used :

```
String complexCommand[] = {"-y", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/DCIM/Sinha's POP/20150530_073113.mp4", "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=3:v=1:a=1",
            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "480x640", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-preset", "ultrafast", savingPath};
```

Here you can clearly see that I've used **setsar=1** and used **-crf only**.

And the logs are :

```
FAILED with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
                                                         built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                         configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                         libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
                                                         libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
                                                         libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
                                                         libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
                                                         libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
                                                         libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
                                                         libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
                                                         libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
                                                       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4':
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           major_brand     : isom
                                                           minor_version   : 512
                                                           compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
                                                           encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
                                                         Duration: 00:02:47.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 245 kb/s
                                                           Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], 112 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                           Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             handler_name    : SoundHandler
                                                       Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4':
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           major_brand     : mp42
                                                           minor_version   : 0
                                                           compatible_brands: isommp42
                                                           creation_time   : 2013-12-15 13:11:41
                                                         Duration: 00:03:51.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1693 kb/s
                                                           Stream #1:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1498 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             handler_name    : VideoHandler
                                                           Stream #1:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             creation_time   : 2013-12-15 13:11:41
                                                             handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
                                                       Input #2, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/mnt/m_external_sd/DCIM/Sinha's POP/20150530_073113.mp4':
                                                         Metadata:
                                                           major_brand     : isom
                                                           minor_version   : 0
                                                           compatible_brands: isom3gp4
                                                           creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                         Duration: 00:04:48.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3608 kb/s
                                                           Stream #2:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x480, 3478 kb/s, 30.28 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                             handler_name    : VideoHandle
                                                             encoder         :                                
                                                           Stream #2:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
                                                           Metadata:
                                                             creation_time   : 2015-05-30 02:06:06
                                                             handler_name    : SoundHandle
                                                       [Parsed_concat_4 @ 0xa7ea91d0] Input link in2:v0 parameters (size 720x480, SAR 0:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (480x640, SAR 1:1)
                                                       [Parsed_concat_4 @ 0xa7ea91d0] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_4
                                                       Error configuring complex filters.
                                                       Invalid argument
```

**NOTE:** *I have tried using setsar=1/1 but still got the same result.*

Comment: The console output is not complete. Your command with three inputs is missing the additional input labels to the concat filter. You can change `setsar=1:1` to `setsar=1` (although in some answers I've used `1/1` just to show the proper syntax). libx264 ignores `-q` so you can remove it and keep using `-crf` instead.

Comment: I've tried using your suggested stuff in my code but still no luck buddy. Please see my edits too in order to get the console output. Thanks

Comment: @LordNeckbeard see now please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You omitted the filterchain for your third input and you did not provide enough inputs to concat. Change the command to:

```
String complexCommand[] = {"-y", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/DCIM/Sinha's POP/20150530_073113.mp4", "-filter_complex",
            "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v2];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1",
            "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "480x640", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-preset", "ultrafast", savingPath};
```

The only additional thing I did was to remove `-strict experimental`. Only old versions need that. I left everything else the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Since I've implemented your code and it worked fine is there any way in the above code to increase the speed of the merging/concatenating? If yes then guide me with the same as it is taking more than 6 minutes which is too much for the user to wait for the merging.

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma Please use a pastebin site to show your command and the complete console output/log from the command. Then provide the link here.

Comment: Will do that but do you have any solution for the above problem I asked from you. Never used the pastebin before and I think it is paid.

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma I can't make any suggestions without the command and console output/log. By "pastebin" I meant any pastebin type of service. There are dozens: all free.

Comment: The console output is too long when the concatenation actually happens. Since the above process took 11 min 35 sec to merge three videos. So you really want all the console output?

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma Yes, it is required. Please include everything until the `frame=` stuff. You can exclude lines like `frame=  425 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=      68kB time=00:00:14.84 bitrate=  37.5kbits` and everything afterwards.

Comment: Since the code too much of memory pastebin didn't allow me to share this. So I've used my drive to share the output with you. If I have done something wrong please remind me of that and thank you again for showing interest in my problem. Here is the link : [ffmpeg output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HHj8bBVOhYeCNizomHCFroI70GCxQhfkvWlX5ei8t0k)

Comment: @AlokKumarVerma Unfortunately that does not contain the output log from the `ffmpeg` process. Run the `ffmpeg` command with the `-report` option and it will output a text file named similarly to `ffmpeg-20171011-084745.log`

Comment: Could you please tell me the command or where to put the -report in the command? and does this report comes when the command is implemented through android?

Comment: so the command begins with this "-report","-y", "-i". Acknowledge that so that I will start working on it and will give you the desired result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156499/discussion-between-alok-kumar-verma-and-lordneckbeard).

Comment: @AmitSharma Yes

Answer (score 1):

```
String cmd[] = {"-y", "-i", "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-i", 
                "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-i", 
                "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/Brodha V - Aathma Raama [Music Video]_HD.mp4", "-i", 
                "/mnt/m_external_sd/Videos/VID-20161221-WA0000.mp4", "-filter_complex",
                "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v1];[2:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v2];[3:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1[v3];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a][v2][2:a][v3][3:a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1",
                "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "480x640", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-preset", "ultrafast", outputFile};
```